# problema al realizar una petición con dio en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, post

tengo una duda, resulta ser que cada 1.5 segundo genero doble petición post, pero hay una petición en particular que se realiza respetando la cantidad de tiempo, pero llega un momento en que no me deja hacer más peticiones y tengo que esperar unos 15 segundos para volver a realizar las peticiones, hice pruebas con otro endpoint más sencillo y si deja enviar peticiones a esa velocidad y probe de forma individual y esta es la unica que me genera ese problema.

```
   final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
            final data = {
                    'Token': await storage.read(key: 'token'),
           };

  final body = {
      'Token' : data['Token'],
      'SP' : myProvider.sp,
      'BT' : code,  
      'C' : widget.tC,
      'C1' : myProvider.idco,
      
    };
 


  try {
    final status = await checkConnectionStatus2(context);
    if(status.statusToken == true ){

   final dio = Dio();

   final response = await dio.post('$apiUrl2', data:body).timeout(Duration(seconds: 4));
```